# SSRS - Print order issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder

I have the following scenario: I have a matrix table with dynamic rows and columns, the rows have three groups *Product_Type*, *Manufacturer* and *Supplier* the Columns are stores that are dynamically generated. All the data comes from a single `DataSet` returned from a stored procedure in SQL Server.

The rows are to big too fit on a single screen and the columns as well, now when this happens the print order must be as follow: if the columns overflows then the columns must print on the following page continuing with all of the rows (the 3 types). If the rows overflows but not the columns then that columns must display on the following page for the remaining rows. These two scenarios is quite straight forward and I already got it to work. If both the columns both overflows it must print as the following picture:

[image]

I am struggling to get it right, I am not a novice in SSRS and only know the fundamentals. I have struggled quite a while trying to figure it out and can't seem to get it right.

Any expert advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this if you have two matrixes one after the other.

The first you hide any columns # > x (where x is the number of columns you can fit onto a page)  and subsequent matrix hide the column # <= x

**Matrix 1**

[image: Matrix 1]

**Matrix 2**

[image: <atrix 2]